# Removed Stylesheet from application but it still appears on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I remove a stylesheet that contained media queries for specific devices. The changes appear on my local version. When I view it in production on heroku the media queries are still there. I asset removed it from the assets initializer `# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( apps.css )`. I ran `heroku run assets:clean` and restarted the server but it still remains. `git status` shows that there are not uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do a couple of more steps:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
$ git add .
$ git commit
... deploy to heroku
```

`rake assets:clean` just removes the compiled assets locally; without running the precompile step to generate new assets, the assets on heroku does not get refreshed.